# Julia: plot with a really large title

Tags: plot, text, julia, overflow

I have to make a plot with a long title but the words overflow from the picture instead of breaking into two or three lines. How can I avoid this text overflow.

```
using LinearAlgebra
x = y = range(-3, stop = 3, length = 100)
surface(x, y, (x, y) -> sinc(norm([x, y])), title="A very long title with a lot of simple words none of them are really large")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Plots
gr()
x = y = range(-3, stop = 3, length = 100)
surface(x, y, (x, y) -> sinc(norm([x, y])), title="A very long title with \na lot of simple words none of them \nare really large")
```

[image]

in case you are using plotly and plotlyjs, you need to use the html line break argument `<br>`

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Plots
plotlyjs()
x = y = range(-3, stop = 3, length = 100)
surface(x, y, (x, y) -> sinc(norm([x, y])), title="A very long title with <br>a lot of simple words none of them <br>are really large")
```

[image]